# Php automatic time countdown(timer) as soon as a record is inserted

Tags: php, html, mysql, timer

I have a table [image: vehicle] for saving details including logging time.Just as soon as a new record is inserted I want the column 'Countdown' to start an automatic time countdown from 30min until it gets to zero(0).How do I go about it?Thanks.
Here is the table php code

```
`<?php $results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT 
 Vehicle_name,Vehicle_make,Vehicle_color,Number_plate,Date,Time FROM 
 vehicle"); ?>
 <div class="table">
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Vehicle name</th>
        <th>Vehicle make</th>
        <th>Vehicle color</th>
        <th>Reg Number</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Countdown</th>

        <th colspan="4">Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['Vehicle_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Vehicle_make']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Vehicle_color']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Number_plate']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Time']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Time']; ?></td>            
        <td>
            <a href="php_code.php?del=<?php echo $row['Number_plate']; ?>" 
        class="del_btn">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

`

Comment: What do you mean with *"automatic time countdown"*? How should it behave? An activly changing, visible field can only be achieved with JavaScript.

Comment: PHP is not the best way to implement count down, use javascript instead. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone can you help me with any link I can make use of.Thanks.

Comment: You've already got a link by @catcon. You should clarify your question.